# Any way to have a many-buildfile structure in FAKE?

Tags: f#, f#-fake, f#-fake-4

In [FAKE](http://fsharp.github.com/FAKE/) you typically have a buildscript like:

```
// "foo.fsx"
#r @"./packages/tools/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"

open Fake

Target "Foo" (fun _ -> trace "Here I am, foo the size of a bar" )

Run "Foo"
```

Which works fine. Now suppose you want another buildscript, called "bar.fsx",

```
// "bar.fsx"
#r @"./packages/tools/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"
#load "foo.fsx"

open Fake

Target "Bar" (fun _ -> trace "And you have me building software ..." )

Run "Bar"
```

This is now wrong. If you try and run "bar.fsx" it will first execute the task "Foo" even though I didn't explicitly ask for that as a dependency. It's because the `load` directive runs the `foo.fsx` script.

So, my question is, how can I import the `foo.fsx` file, obtain all the Targets, but not execute say the `Run` command. Or perhaps more interestingly, and what I really want to do; how can I share `Target`s between scripts in FAKE?

It doesn't help if I put the `Target` definitions into a module, like so:

```
module FooTargets =
    Target "Foo" (fun _ -> trace "Here I am, foo the size of a bar" )
```

which is perhaps mildly surprising to me ...

Appreciate any advice on how to accomplish this. My "best" idea so far has been to define some constant in say 'foo.fsx' and then conditionally `load` it in all other scripts. This seems pretty offensive, though (edit: and happily, not even possible.)

-- Update: Below is a more complete (i.e. runnable) example. It fails with FAKE 2.2.12.0, with a Duplicate Key error, as the module Common has been loaded twice, and FAKE has populated the target dictionary with the same "Env" target.

```
// "common.fsx"
#r     @"../../tools/FAKE/FakeLib.dll"

open Fake

module Common = 
    Target "Env" (fun _ -> trace "Env")
```

,

```
// "foo.fsx"
#r     @"../../tools/FAKE/FakeLib.dll"
#load  @"common.fsx"

open Fake

module Foo =
    Target "Foo" (fun _ -> trace "Here I am, foo the size of a bar" )

"Env" ==> "Foo"
```

,

```
// "bar.fsx"
#r     @"../../tools/FAKE/FakeLib.dll"
#load  @"common.fsx"

open Fake

module Bar =
    Target "Bar" (fun _ -> trace "And you have me building software ..."  )

"Env" ==> "Bar"
```

,

```
// "marvin.fsx"
#r     @"../../tools/FAKE/FakeLib.dll"

#load  @"common.fsx"
#load  @"foo.fsx"
#load  @"bar.fsx"

open Fake

module Marvin =
    Target "Marvin" (fun _ -> ())

"Bar" ==> "Marvin"
"Foo" ==> "Marvin"

Run "Marvin"
```

Build with: `fake.exe Marvin.fsx`.

Error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<StartupCode$FSI_0002>.$FSI_0002_Common$fsx' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Fake.TargetHelper.targetFromTemplate[a](TargetTemplate`1 template, String name, a parameters)
   at Fake.TargetHelper.TargetTemplateWithDependecies@140.Invoke(String name, a parameters)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0002>.$FSI_0002_Common$fsx..cctor() in c:\Users\Noon\dev\beep\common.fsx:line 7
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0002>.$FSI_0002_Foo$fsx.main@() in c:\Users\Noon\dev\beep\foo.fsx:line 8
Stopped due to error
Searching for process with name = fsi.exe
Searching for process with name = msbuild
```

Comment: I suspect the problem - at least in your example is that you call `#load` on the same file twice, which will almost certainly produce bad results

Comment: @JohnPalmer - That's exactly the point. I need to not have the `load` call define the `Target`s again. So how to do that? (obvious answer: "Don't call `load`". But what then?)

Comment: I think this is not possible at the moment. We should discuss it on the feature request at https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/issues/250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/silky/bf304785a46db32b5cc8) a solution I came up with. I had to separate out the targets from the build process, due to the realities of `#load` and the FAKE process for running targets. But it at least accomplishes my goal. I'm not entirely sure how I feel about it, because of the "loose" connection between the inter-file dependencies; but perhaps one could argue that that is a good thing.

Answer (score 10):

In [Build.Tools](https://github.com/15below/Build.Tools) we ended up putting the code for the various targets in different script files as normal F# functions, and then composing the targets together in a [Core.fsx](https://github.com/15below/Build.Tools/blob/master/Core.fsx) that sets up the targets and their dependencies.

One of the things on my low priority todo list is actually to separate Core into two files - one which builds up the configuration and target definitions, and one which sets up the dependencies and calls `Run`. In that way you could re-use all underlying targets while defining different runners that didn't have to include the full default dependency tree.

The current `Core.fsx` looks like this:

```
#r    "./fake/fakelib.dll"
#load "./Utils.fsx"
#load "./Packaging.fsx"
#load "./Versioning.fsx"
#load "./Solution.fsx"
#load "./Test.fsx"
#load "./Specflow.fsx"

open System.IO
open Fake

let config = 
    Map.ofList [
        "build:configuration", environVarOrDefault "configuration"         "Release"
        "build:solution",      environVar          "solution"
        "core:tools",          environVar          "tools"
        "packaging:output",    environVarOrDefault "output"                (sprintf "%s\output" (Path.GetFullPath(".")))
        "packaging:updateid",  environVarOrDefault "updateid"              ""
        "packaging:pushurl",   environVarOrDefault "pushurl"               ""
        "packaging:apikey",    environVarOrDefault "apikey"                ""
        "packaging:packages",  environVarOrDefault "packages"              ""
        "versioning:build",    environVarOrDefault "build_number"          "0"
        "versioning:branch",   match environVar "teamcity_build_branch" with
                                   | "<default>" -> environVar "vcsroot_branch"
                                   | _ -> environVar "teamcity_build_branch"
    ]

Target "Default"           <| DoNothing
Target "Packaging:Package" <| Packaging.package config
Target "Packaging:Restore" <| Packaging.restore config
Target "Packaging:Update"  <| Packaging.update config
Target "Packaging:Push"    <| Packaging.push config
Target "Solution:Build"    <| Solution.build config
Target "Solution:Clean"    <| Solution.clean config
Target "Versioning:Update" <| Versioning.update config
Target "Test:Run"          <| Test.run config
Target "SpecFlow:Run"      <| Specflow.run config

"Solution:Clean"
    ==> "Packaging:Restore"
    ==> "Versioning:Update"
    ==> "Solution:Build"
    ==> "Packaging:Package"
    ==> "SpecFlow:Run"
    ==> "Test:Run"
    =?> ("Packaging:Push", not isLocalBuild)
    ==> "Default"

RunParameterTargetOrDefault "target" "Default"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Indeed, splitting up the .fsx files into _targets and _builds was what I did as well, so glad to know it makes some sort of sense. You also seem to have adopted a similar structure with the 'Utils.fsx' not defining any targets (otherwise it would crash with duplicate targets). Nice to know this is a somewhat standard approach.